# Loop through items created in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have custom post type.

How it is possible to loop through the page created in this custom post type please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more info?  Your question is asking if "it's possible" and the answer to that is "Yes".  But I'm sure you're looking for more information than just whether or not it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to create a custom post type template for this and fetch the posts there, You will find details regarding how to create a template file here:[Custom Post Type Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/).
Create a page for the custom posts to show and assign the template file created.
More details can be found here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get the posts of a custom post type depending on where you want to use the results.

If you're getting the results in order to process the data you can use `get_posts`

```
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'status'=> 'publish'
  'post_type'   => 'my_post_type'
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($posts as $post) { 
//Write code here
}
```

If you're trying to display your posts in a template, then you can follow the advice of @dhl17